# lm-sensors does not detect intel gpu

Tags: gpu, temperature, intel-graphics, optimus, lm-sensors

I want to monitor the temperature and fan speed of my intel gpu. However, sensors does not seem to detect it:

```
niko@dell-xps15: ~ $ sudo sensors-detect
Password: 
# sensors-detect revision 6284 (2015-05-31 14:00:33 +0200)
# System: Dell Inc. XPS 15 9550 (laptop)
# Board: Dell Inc. 0N7TVV
# Kernel: 4.4.14 x86_64
# Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz (6/94/3)

This program will help you determine which kernel modules you need
to load to use lm_sensors most effectively. It is generally safe
and recommended to accept the default answers to all questions,
unless you know what you're doing.

Some south bridges, CPUs or memory controllers contain embedded sensors.
Do you want to scan for them? This is totally safe. (YES/no): 
Silicon Integrated Systems SIS5595...                       No
VIA VT82C686 Integrated Sensors...                          No
VIA VT8231 Integrated Sensors...                            No
AMD K8 thermal sensors...                                   No
AMD Family 10h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 11h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 12h and 14h thermal sensors...                   No
AMD Family 15h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 16h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 15h power sensors...                             No
AMD Family 16h power sensors...                             No
Intel digital thermal sensor...                             Success!
    (driver `coretemp')
Intel AMB FB-DIMM thermal sensor...                         No
Intel 5500/5520/X58 thermal sensor...                       No
VIA C7 thermal sensor...                                    No
VIA Nano thermal sensor...                                  No

Some Super I/O chips contain embedded sensors. We have to write to
standard I/O ports to probe them. This is usually safe.
Do you want to scan for Super I/O sensors? (YES/no): 
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x2e/0x2f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     Yes
Found unknown chip with ID 0x1d00
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x4e/0x4f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      No

Some hardware monitoring chips are accessible through the ISA I/O ports.
We have to write to arbitrary I/O ports to probe them. This is usually
safe though. Yes, you do have ISA I/O ports even if you do not have any
ISA slots! Do you want to scan the ISA I/O ports? (YES/no): 
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM78' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM79' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `Winbond W83781D' at 0x290...                   No
Probing for `Winbond W83782D' at 0x290...                   No

Lastly, we can probe the I2C/SMBus adapters for connected hardware
monitoring devices. This is the most risky part, and while it works
reasonably well on most systems, it has been reported to cause trouble
on some systems.
Do you want to probe the I2C/SMBus adapters now? (YES/no): 
Found unknown SMBus adapter 8086:a123 at 0000:00:1f.4.
Sorry, no supported PCI bus adapters found.

Next adapter: Synopsys DesignWare I2C adapter (i2c-0)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): 
Adapter doesn't support all probing functions.
Some addresses won't be probed.

Next adapter: Synopsys DesignWare I2C adapter (i2c-1)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): 
Adapter doesn't support all probing functions.
Some addresses won't be probed.

Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpc (i2c-2)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpb (i2c-3)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpd (i2c-4)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: DPDDC-A (i2c-5)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes
Client found at address 0x5c
Probing for `Analog Devices ADT7462'...                     No
Probing for `SMSC EMC1072'...                               No
Probing for `SMSC EMC1073'...                               No
Probing for `SMSC EMC1074'...                               No

Next adapter: DPDDC-B (i2c-6)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: DPDDC-C (i2c-7)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes


Now follows a summary of the probes I have just done.
Just press ENTER to continue: 

Driver `coretemp':
  * Chip `Intel digital thermal sensor' (confidence: 9)

Do you want to overwrite /etc/sysconfig/lm_sensors? (YES/no): 
Copy prog/init/lm_sensors.init to /etc/init.d/lm_sensors
for initialization at boot time.
You should now start the lm_sensors service to load the required
kernel modules.
```

The contents of `/etc/sysconfig/lm_sensors`:

```
# Generated by sensors-detect on Tue Jul 19 22:27:04 2016
# This file is sourced by /etc/init.d/lm_sensors and defines the modules to
# be loaded/unloaded.
#
# The format of this file is a shell script that simply defines variables:
# HWMON_MODULES for hardware monitoring driver modules, and optionally
# BUS_MODULES for any required bus driver module (for example for I2C or SPI).

HWMON_MODULES="coretemp"
```

Can this be related to the fact that I also have nvidia gpu as well and I am using bumblebee to switch between the two GPUs?

The GPUs are Intel(R) HD Graphics 530 and NVIDIA GTX 960M. OS is Slackware 14.2.

Is there a fix or can I monitor the intel gpu sensors using another tool?